# How to download PDF from URL using Python if URL is not a simple .pdf, but also contains more information such as signature, etc?

Tags: python, pdf, python-requests, power-automate, urlparse

I have a URL to a PDF that looks like this:

```
https://....blob.core.windows.net/../.../../signedefiles/.....pdf?sv=date&se=2023-11-17T16%3A35%3A35Z&sr=b&sp=r&rscc=no-store&rscd=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22ABC+QRZ+8112+2022.pdf%22&rsct=application%2Fpdf&sig=ABCDEF%2GHIJK%2123%3D
```

I need to download this pdf from this URL using Python. I know I can download from simple URLs as such:

```
import requests
url = 'https://ssrcontentstore.blob.core.windows.net/ssrclientpostdata-2022/ssr00002451/a6b21d6a-4da8-4e01-ac79-7fadcb2712e8/signedefiles/FM%20tax%208879%202022.pdf?sv=2021-06-08&se=2023-11-17T16%3A35%3A35Z&sr=b&sp=r&rscc=no-store&rscd=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22FM+tax+8879+2022.pdf%22&rsct=application%2Fpdf&sig=o3cuyUYf%2B7hujd8sjeXxbnF0HwgbJ%2BIqSSZiYVGaP60%3D'
response = requests.get(url)
with open('sample.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

But for a complicated URL like the one I showed above, which seems to have signature etc in the URL - I am unable to use the same code with success. Any idea on what would need to be added here to make a URL like this work?
I am able to use PowerAutomate's `Upload File From URL` action to download the PDF very easily by passing just this URL. So I know that the URL is accurate, but I cannot use PowerAutomate for the rest of this process so I'm wondering if I can figure it out in Python or Alteryx. Doing a simple Download from URL in Alteryx does not work either. I believe I will have to pass the signature or other things from the URL but I'm not sure what and how. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: first you have to find web page with all links to needed `PDF`. Next you can try to use `requests` to get this page and `BeautifulSoup` to get links from HTML, and again `requests` to download files. OR it may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) if page uses `JavaScript` to generate links on page.

Comment: There is not 1 web page... there is always a different URL returned by a webhook. And I need to get the PDF from that URL..

Comment: so you have to get URL from webhook.

Comment: Yes I get the URL from the webhook each time successfully, but then unable to pass that URL in python to download the PDF from that URL

Comment: maybe real browser uses `cookies` to keep some data - and maybe later server check `cookies` with information in `url`. And this may need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser, and it needs to load original page to get all `cookies` from server, and later download file using `cookeis` from browser (or click on link in browser to download it.

Comment: when I use url in browser then it shows `Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly...` - maybe it needs special `headers` in request. If you can download it in browser then you should use `DevTools` (tab `Network`) in `Chrome` or `Friefox` to see what data it sends to server when you click link in browser. It may send special headers, and cookies, and it may use `POST` instead of `GET` - and all this is importat. If you have to login in browser to get this link then your code has to also login to server.